# how to provision okta with sql database user table

Tags: okta, okta-api

I have enterprise application(say xyz) which is developed in asp.net mvc and deployed in Azure App service. our database deployed in azure virtual machine. user management flow is written in xyz application (like authentication, registration, active -deactive etc) and it store in tblUsers.

I have been asked to integrate okta for authentication (single sign-on with SAML 2.0), and provisioning.

Somehow I have managed integration for authentication with the help of below link
https://github.com/bvillanueva-mdsol/OktaSaml2OwinSample

could you please help me to understand to synchronize users bi-directional.
so

1. if okta admin create user it should update in xyz application database user table.
2. if a user has been created through xyz application , get updated or added user in Okta.

I have gone through below link but it is not fruitful
https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Provisioning/lcm/lcm-provision-application.htm

note : user role provisioning not in scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Types of provisioning in okta

1. Upstream (to okta) :
   follow postman link which is provided by Okta
   https://app.getpostman.com/run-collection/9daeb4b935a423c39009
   you have to just create API token from Okta and pass it to postman header
   [image]
   [image]
2. Downstream (from okta)
   please refer below link
   [How to construct valid event Webhook endpoint/url for OKTA Event Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70965883/how-to-construct-valid-event-webhook-endpoint-url-for-okta-event-hook)

Comment: import users in Okta 
1. bulk import through csv file 
2. real time  import 
   2.1 okta having couple way to import real time user , in case your user store in active directory, LDAP 
   2.2  Active directory console agent 
3. Inline Hook :  is for to change some attribute (or user activation process)  which is imported from other source like csv, active directory.  So based on my requirement i choosen event hook , bulk upload CSV and api to create user

Comment: one more option (if you don't have user store in Active directory) i.e Called SCIM https://github.com/FabianZoon/SCIM2

Answer (score 1):

Usually it's not a good idea to go bi-directional, but...

You need to implement a connector to your application which will support user provisioning and user import operations.

Use this https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Provisioning/opp/OPP-main.htm to get yourself started. You can either go SCIM or OPP route, depending on your requirements (OPP will require you to have a VM with OPP agent running on it)

Comment: could you please illustrate "Usually it's not a good idea to go bi-directional".
you mean legacy system must use high level of user store (like Active directory) first ,than integrate and provision with oka. 
it seems developer (free) okta account doesn't allow to do provision or de-provision

Comment: I mean, it's better when all the changes are done at one place, then it's considered a trusted source. It's better from management, security and other perspectives

Comment: I think solution is configure workflow , https://youtu.be/j2yLobP5Mt8

Comment: You can go this route also, if you can reach from the internet into your own network. Workflows runs on the Internet and can use APIs or other pre-configured connectors to reach out to your application, if you have a public endpoint to expose for Workflows

Comment: could you please help me to understand other root , little bit in detail. I would be thankful.

Comment: Sure, what exactly you do not understand and needs more clarification?

Comment: provisioning deployment diagram
1. upstream (to okta)
2. downstream (from okta)
when users store in local database.